# Alfresco errors

Tags: java, alfresco, hazelcast

Can someone help me with the following errors:

```
3:02:19,562 ERROR [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] Exception from executeScript - redirecting to status template error: 10021817710 Wrapped Exception (with status template): [CONCURRENT_MAP_GET] Operation Timeout (with no response!): 20000
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 10021817710 Wrapped Exception (with status template): [CONCURRENT_MAP_GET] Operation Timeout (with no response!): 20000
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:171)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$3.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:422)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:450)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:491)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:529)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:341)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:378)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:132)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.hazelcast.core.OperationTimeoutException: [CONCURRENT_MAP_GET] Operation Timeout (with no response!): 20000
    at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$ResponseQueueCall.waitAndGetResult(BaseManager.java:619)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$ResponseQueueCall.getRedoAwareResult(BaseManager.java:641)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$ResponseQueueCall.getResult(BaseManager.java:636)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$RequestBasedCall.getResultAsObject(BaseManager.java:464)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$ResponseQueueCall.getResultAsObject(BaseManager.java:555)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$RequestBasedCall.getResultAsObject(BaseManager.java:460)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$ResponseQueueCall.getResultAsObject(BaseManager.java:555)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$RequestBasedCall.objectCall(BaseManager.java:502)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$ResponseQueueCall.objectCall(BaseManager.java:555)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$RequestBasedCall.objectCall(BaseManager.java:508)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$ResponseQueueCall.objectCall(BaseManager.java:555)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.ConcurrentMapManager$MGet.get(ConcurrentMapManager.java:1124)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.MProxyImpl$MProxyReal.get(MProxyImpl.java:781)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.MProxyImpl.get(MProxyImpl.java:114)
    at org.alfresco.repo.lock.mem.AbstractLockStore.get(AbstractLockStore.java:61)
    at org.alfresco.enterprise.repo.cluster.lock.HazelcastLockStore.get(HazelcastLockStore.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor332.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.alfresco.enterprise.repo.cluster.core.ClusteredObjectProxyFactory$AbstractClusteredObjectProxyInvoker.invoke(ClusteredObjectProxyFactory.java:275)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.lock.mem.LockableAspectInterceptor.invoke(LockableAspectInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.hasAspect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor261.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.alfresco.repo.tenant.MultiTNodeServiceInterceptor.invoke(MultiTNodeServiceInterceptor.java:104)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.hasAspect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor261.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.alfresco.repo.service.StoreRedirectorProxyFactory$RedirectorInvocationHandler.invoke(StoreRedirectorProxyFactory.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.hasAspect(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.MLPropertyInterceptor.getPivotNodeRef(MLPropertyInterceptor.java:324)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.MLPropertyInterceptor.invoke(MLPropertyInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.enterprise.repo.sync.SyncPropertyInterceptor.invoke(SyncPropertyInterceptor.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.NodeRefPropertyMethodInterceptor.invoke(NodeRefPropertyMethodInterceptor.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getProperty(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor260.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getProperty(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.person.PersonServiceImpl.getPersonOrNullImpl(PersonServiceImpl.java:552)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.person.PersonServiceImpl.personExists(PersonServiceImpl.java:516)
    at org.alfresco.repo.model.Repository.getFullyAuthenticatedPerson(Repository.java:271)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.addRepoParameters(RepositoryContainer.java:234)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.getScriptParameters(RepositoryContainer.java:190)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createScriptParameters(AbstractWebScript.java:669)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:81)
    ... 27 more
13:02:19,656 WARN  [org.alfresco.enterprise.repo.cluster.cache.HazelcastSimpleCache] Can't get value from cluster for cache HazelcastSimpleCache[cacheName=cache.aclSharedCache], key=AclEntity[ ID=718467, version=2538900, aclId=c51ff8f7-b2de-4891-a40d-85a57e66a09e, isLatest=true, aclVersion=1, inherits=true, inheritsFrom=718466, type=2, inheritedAcl=718467, isVersioned=false, requiresVersion=false, aclChangeSet=68236281]
13:02:19,765 WARN  [org.alfresco.enterprise.repo.cluster.cache.HazelcastSimpleCache] Can't get value from cluster for cache HazelcastSimpleCache[cacheName=cache.ticketsCache], key=77b86475f7d72a489685c1b27ed4d908c9e8121c
13:02:19,765 WARN  [org.alfresco.enterprise.repo.cluster.cache.HazelcastSimpleCache] Can't get value from cluster for cache HazelcastSimpleCache[cacheName=cache.ticketsCache], key=905318b647d82d3b29ec6c41e0f926a3ffc9bba7
13:02:20,124 WARN  [org.alfresco.enterprise.repo.cluster.cache.HazelcastSimpleCache] Can't get value from cluster for cache HazelcastSimpleCache[cacheName=cache.ticketsCache], key=662ceb1110e795ae1ca2a3af0c8380bfdc67c495
13:02:20,312 WARN  [org.alfresco.enterprise.repo.cluster.cache.HazelcastSimpleCache] Can't get value from cluster for cache HazelcastSimpleCache[cacheName=cache.ticketsCache], key=cb0b43102deb2f15b71625c047d548998677c8dc
13:02:20,624 ERROR [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] Exception from executeScript - redirecting to status template error: 10021817712 Wrapped Exception (with status template): [CONCURRENT_MAP_GET] Operation Timeout (with no response!): 20000
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 10021817712 Wrapped Exception (with status template): [CONCURRENT_MAP_GET] Operation Timeout (with no response!): 20000
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:171)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$3.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:422)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:450)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:491)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:529)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:341)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:378)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:132)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.hazelcast.core.OperationTimeoutException: [CONCURRENT_MAP_GET] Operation Timeout (with no response!): 20000
```

What could cause them? The application which is using Alfresco Tomcat just hangs when this (and a lot more) is logged in the Alfresco log. I am not very familiar with the technology, but if any information is needed I can try to provide it

Only restart of the SQL services on the DB server and/or (because it is not always the same) restart of the Alfresco service on the Application server resolves the issue, but for a few days only, then the application hangs with the above error.

Comment: From the logs we can see that Alfresco cluster is trying to access Hazelcast cluster but for some reason the operation times out. Check if the network connection is up, Hazelcast cluster is up. Also check CPU, JVM logs etc. The problem is the communication between Alfresco and HZ

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Orçun Çolak in the comments, the exception comes from a timeout of your hazelcast cache cluster, but this is probably not the actual problem, just the symptom. I would guess that on your DB server and/or on the Alfresco jdbc connection pool the maximum number of connections has run out. However, this should be in the log on one of the cluster nodes.

Try to analyze the database server if the problem occurs again.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. DB team is investigating. If they find a solution , I will post it here

Comment: The problem occurs on every 30 to max 48 hours .DB team says everything on the DB server is OK. No issues with SQL . They run the checks while alfreso is logging the concurrent_map_get/put errors. Each time this happens only alfresco restart is "fixing" the issue . The system is stable for a day or two.

Comment: hazelcast timeouts could have many causes similar to printer is not printing. You may also check the jdbc connection pool on the Alfresco site too. Since Alfresco is only packaged with hazelcast in the Enterprise Edition I suggest you contact commercial support or at least consult someone who is familiar with your stack.